# Systemd host-only bridge

Tags: networking, linux-networking, systemd, bridge, systemd-networkd

I'm trying to create a bridge device for host to virtual machine only communication with systemd networking.

Currently I have a netdev and a network file. The bridge is created after a restart of networking but it does not get the IP assigned nor is it up.

The only hint I currently have that something is amiss is a journal entry: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): intbr0: link is not ready

Am I missing something for bridges without an assigned physical device?

---

Netdev file:

```
[NetDev]
Name=intbr0
Kind=bridge
```

Network file:

```
[Match]
Name=intbr0

[Network]
Address=10.110.0.1/24
```

Comment: The configs themselves look fine to me ...